# if user_name is already registered, redirect back to the same page ex. register.php?q=user_exists

Tags: php, mysqli

this the php part

```
<?php
include 'assets/db.php';

if(isset($_POST["register"])){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, email, user_name, pass) 

           VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"])."',
                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"])."', 
                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["user_name"])."', 
                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["pass"])."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location='_sign_in.php?l=1';</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error! Please refresh the page and try again.');</script>";
}
$conn->close();
```

i am trying to avoid re-registration of any user_name, if user_name is already registered, redirect back to some page example-  register.php?q=user_exists.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: i see nothing in the code that checks that a user name already exists.

Comment: Are you sure that the INSERT of a duplicate user will actually error? Is someting in there set to unique?

Comment: ohh, what commands are used to check that ?

Comment: use `select` statement before insert for checking

Comment: ___Plain Text Password___ YUK! Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: @rtfm it could be a DB unique constraint

Comment: a. set name as unique and check that after making the query, b. a select query for that name first

Comment: @PadraigD well i was not sure if that was the question here or not :-)

Comment: @rtfm If a unique constraint is set there is no need to check for duplicate with a select, just try to insert and if it fails with error 1062, there is a duplicate.

Comment: @Geoffrey a. b. they were 2 options. sometimes you need b as you need the id from the dupe for further processing

Comment: @rtfm, Ah, sorry I misinterpreted your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicate user names, add a unique index to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE(`user_name`)
```

This will cause the insert to fail allowing you to detect the failure without needing an additional `SELECT` to check for a duplicate.

If you want to ensure the error is due to a duplicate value, check for mysql error 1062

```
Error: 1062 SQLSTATE: 23000 (ER_DUP_ENTRY)
```

You can check for this by using [mysqli::errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) and then redirect by simply sending the Location header, ie:

```
if (!$conn->query($sql))
{
  if ($conn->errno == 1062)
  {
    header("Location: register.php?q=user_exists");
    die();
  }

  die('Critical Failure');
}
```

Edit: Instead of just down voting, how about commenting on what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: looks solid to me, not sure why the down votes, you may need to explain how to find the error code